# Is the perl module Perl-LDAP (Net::LDAP) thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety

I've been searching for an answer to this question everywhere I can think of, but I haven't come across a firm answer.

This is the main page for the module: http://ldap.perl.org/
It links to documentation, but in my searches of the docs, I've found no mention of thread safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.4001, apparently not.  Notice this comment from the file LDAP/Message.pm:

```
# We do this here so when we add threading we can lock it
```

So it would seem that the author, at least at some point in the past, was intending to add thread support, but admittedly had not yet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Using Net::LDAP, I was getting mysterious errors that reeked of multi-threading issues, and the comments provide enough suspicion that this is probably the cause.